# TestNG report in IntelliJ does not show cucumber scenario and step details

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber, testng

I am using below combination for my UI automation code.

1. Selenium
2. Java
3. Cucumber
4. TestNG
5. Maven

When I run my CukesRunner class to execute the feature files, it runs successfully. But the TestNG window in Intellij show only till the feature name and the scenario/step details are missing.

[image]

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by the known issue:

- [IDEA-151363](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151363) JUnit Runner - test name is truncated until '.' if it contains '.'

Comment: I did come across similar comments on googling. But it's not the case. There is no '.' in feature, scenario and steps.

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @VelGanesh Did you create the issue? Could you give us the link?